# I have a web add-in manifest.xml file for word but how to deploy those things in server so everybody can use those changes in his machine

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have a web add-in manifest.xml file for word but how to deploy  those things in server so everybody can use those changes in his machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can all possible ways of deploying add-ins described in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.